# How to wait and listen to a webhook while am in a session of another request in python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

```
@app.route("/send-url", methods=["POST"])
def test(id):
    try:
        data = request.json
        # this data should be used as a response for the session in call-back endpoint below
    except Exception as err:
        logger.exception(err)
        return jsonify({"message": False, "error": "Server Error"})


@app.route("/call-back", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def test2():
    try:
        payload = dict(sanitizerRequest(request))
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
        forward_url = "https://app.io/c/ex/d0839b26-1390-4542-a388-766cfdc1e1a4/receive" # to external service

        req = requests.post(forward_url, json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
        status = req.status_code
        if status == 200:
            # The external service only acknowledges with status code here.
            # But it makes a POST on  http://localhost:5000/send-url and it is the values it POSTS that i wanna send as reply here
            response = ......
            #return response
        else:
            res_string =f"Error, we could not forward  {forward_url}. Status code {status}"
            #res_string ='Remote application down'
            return jsonify({"responseString":res_string, "action":"end"}), 200
    except Exception as err:
        res_string ="something went wrong"
        logger.exception(err)
        return jsonify({"responseString":res_string, "action":"end"}), 200
```

In the code snippet above, i have two end points one is used as a callback(`http://domain.xxx/call-back`) by an external service **A**, which makes a GET or POST requests to it, I then forward that request content through the a url `https://app.io/c/ex/d0839b26-1390-4542-a388-766cfdc1e1a4/receive` to another external service **B**.

Now, the external service **B** responds by status code only, but shortly after, it makes a POST request to my second end-point `http://domain.xxx/send-url` which i need as a response to the first external Service **A**.

So, my question is, how do i wait and listen to the second endpoint without dropping the session started when `http://domain.xxx/call-back` was called, so as i can reply to external service **A** with data posted at `http://domain.xxx/send-url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out some time back, i used a redis  list key by making a blocking pop just after i receive statuscode 200 in `test2`,
then the other end at `test1` pushes its computed results to this list, as soon as it pushes it, the blocked pop will return a value.

I also added some timing out to avoid bpop forever.

```
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
key2 = f"MSG_KEY_{some_unique_key}" # define a redis key hia

@app.route("/send-url", methods=["POST"])
def test(id):
    try:
        data = request.json
        # this data should be used as a response for the session in call-back endpoint below
        
        # do some proccesing 
        content  =  proccesing....

        r.lpush(key2, str(content)) # push to redis list
    except Exception as err:
        logger.exception(err)
        return jsonify({"message": False, "error": "Server Error"})


@app.route("/call-back", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def test2():
    try:
        payload = dict(sanitizerRequest(request))
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
        forward_url = "https://app.io/c/ex/d0839b26-1390-4542-a388-766cfdc1e1a4/receive" # to external service

        

        req = requests.post(forward_url, json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
        status = req.status_code
        if status == 200:
            data = r.blpop(key2)  # do a blocking pop on the redis list
            response = data
            #return response
        else:
            res_string =f"Error, we could not forward  {forward_url}. Status code {status}"
            #res_string ='Remote application down'
            return jsonify({"responseString":res_string, "action":"end"}), 200
    except Exception as err:
        res_string ="something went wrong"
        logger.exception(err)
        return jsonify({"responseString":res_string, "action":"end"}), 200
```